# Sprockets 2 With Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

Trying to run Sprockets 2 in a Rails 2.3 app...

After installing the gem and implementing this in config.ru according to [this guide from Pivotal](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/giving-rails-2-the-asset-pipeline)

```
require 'config/environment' if !defined?(Rails) || !Rails.initialized?
require 'sprockets'

unless Rails.env.production?
map '/assets' do
  sprockets = Sprockets::Environment.new
  sprockets.append_path 'app/assets/images'
  sprockets.append_path 'app/assets/javascripts'
  sprockets.append_path 'app/assets/stylesheets'

  Sprockets::Helpers.configure do |config|
    config.environment = sprockets
    config.prefix      = "/assets"
    config.digest      = false
  end

  run sprockets
  end
end

map '/' do
  use Rails::Rack::LogTailer unless Rails.env.test?
  use Rails::Rack::Debugger unless Rails.env.test?
  use Rails::Rack::Static
  run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
end
```

Then I created app/assets and moved the javascripts, images, and stylesheets directories out of public and into app/assets.  Inside of app/assets/javascripts/application.js I have:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Inside of app/assets/stylesheets/application.css I have:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

And of course in layout I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "assets/application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "assets/application" %>
```

Something in my configuration is missing, none of my assets will show up.  Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I had the same issue.  I did a writeup with my solution: http://jaredonline.github.com/blog/2012/05/16/sprockets-2-with-rails-2-dot-3/

Comment: what version of ruby are you using?